# объявление методов в constructor и prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, конструктор

Я только начал изучать JS, и немного застрял. Все говорят что мы можем объявлять методы в прототипе, так как их легче переписать и они будут у всех созданных объектов. Но ведь мы можем так же объявить их в конструкторе, и они так же будут у всех объектов. Я понял что есть разница в использовании памяти, и что в прототипе метод создается только один раз. Но с практической точки зрения эти методы объявленные разным способом делают одно и тоже. В чем разница, и можете привести простой пример где лучше использовать prototype.

Answer (score 2):

Можно делать как угодно.

В конструкторе можно объекту надобавлять методов, и они будут работать ничуть не хуже прототипных. Раньше классов и конструкторов не было. Всё писалось просто в функции, которые начинали работать в особом режиме при операторе `new`, и многие использовали подход без прототипов вообще.

В этом подходе даже несколько плюсов есть. Например можно у одного объекта просто удалить какой-то метод потом. Или переписать какие-то методы - именно заменить, а не сделать второй поверх прототипного. Также при этом проще делается подмешивание поведения вместо наследования. То есть что-то вроде множественного наследования. Ещё был плюс в полноценных приватных переменных, которых нет до сих пор в классах, кроме теперешнего костыля с решёткой.

Такие объекты, как вы и сказали, потребляют больше ресурсов. Но на простых страничках обычно всё равно. И не такой уж страшный там расход, всё весьма легковесное.

Есть один важный нюанс. Обычно инструменты затачиваются под прототипный подход. И большинство js-программистов видимо его поддерживают. Так например в тайпскрипте вы не сможете пользоваться классами-функциями без прототипов, только полноценными классами. Иначе придётся городить какой-то тип вручную каждый раз, поверх уже написанной реализации.

Советую использовать прототипный подход, просто потому что под него всё заточено. И потому что при другом подходе очень легко залипнуть в "мне всё можно напихать в объект" и перестать понимать прототипы и бояться их потом.

Answer (score 1):

Не первостепенной важности момент, и может быть делом вкуса, но нужно ещё учитывать читабельность кода. В нотации классов конструктор станет путаным и перегруженным, если сгрузить туда все методы. Сравните:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  bar() {
    console.log('bar');
  }

  baz() {
    console.log('baz');
  }
}
```

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;

    this.bar = function bar() {
      console.log('bar');
    };

    this.baz = function baz() {
      console.log('baz');
    };
  }
}
```

А если вы начнёте присваивать методы вне конструктора, начнутся уже существенные потери. Сейчас, например, вы потеряете возможность использовать [приватные поля](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields), которые могут быть только внутри декларации класса. И раз уж есть такой прецедент, дальше этот список ограничений может расти.

Comment: Особенная жесть была бы с геттерами/сеттерами в конструкторе

Comment: С другой стороны, если класс выглядит как ваш второй пример, появляются сомнения, нужен ли он вообще) Если выкинуть constructor, использовать обычную функцию = будет -1 уровень вложенности.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty А если вы начнёте присваивать методы вне конструктора, начнутся уже существенные потери.    вы имеете в виду объявление через прототип и что так мы теряем возможность использовать приватные поля?

Comment: Я имел в виду — если мы будем присваивать методы экземплярам класса вне конструктора, мы не сможем использовать приватные поля. Но если будем присваивать экземплярам в конструкторе или присваивать прототипу в декларации класса, тогда сможем)