# зачем нужен свойство prototype?

Tags: javascript

Скажите  в чем отличие, если  например метод walk засунуть прямо в функцию конструктора Human от Human.prototype.walk = function(){}

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256728/

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/prototypes

Comment: Синтаксический сахар, не более